# Newbie starting using Instagram API in Java

Tags: java, api, instagram, discord-jda

I'm new at coding and I'm creating a Discord bot in Java. I used some APIs like "https://random.dog/woof.json" and following some tutorials, I understand that I have to do a request, then I have to use a parser to create some objects (for example an image's URL).
So I wrote that code to get a random dog image, and it works:

```
...
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

...

        URL dogURL = new URL("https://random.dog/woof.json");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(dogURL.openConnection().getInputStream()));

            String lines;

            while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

                array.add(parser.parse(lines));

                for (Object o : array){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) o;

                    url = (String) jsonObject.get("url");
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
```

Now I tried to use Instagram API with my bot: i want users to search someone's Instagram profile and the bot has to show profile's last photo.
So I visited the Instagram API website and I saw it was really different from the other API... So I'd like to ask you how could I request informations from the Instagram API and how could I take someone's last photo.
I'm just really new to coding, so I would be very grateful if someone could post an example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had take a look on instagram API and looks like you can only get those informations for the owner profile(related with the authorization token) and not from his friends and etc.

See: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: So have I to use external APIs to do what i want to do?

Comment: Looking by Instagram API, doesn't looks like you can do what do you want exactlly! :(

Comment: Anytime, Good luck in your project